# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Object[] declaration

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to fix the code of an annoyingly large program (I didn't create it) and I keep getting the famous `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I'd like to mention that I know what the error means, as I've already searched far and wide for an answer but I simply don't understand **why** I'm getting it, so here goes...

Here is the Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at edu.harvard.i2b2.crc.loader.dao.ObservationFactDAO$ObservationFactInsert.insert(ObservationFactDAO.java:359)
at edu.harvard.i2b2.crc.loader.dao.ObservationFactInsertHandle.insertObservationFact(ObservationFactInsertHandle.java:25)
at edu.harvard.i2b2.crc.loader.ejb.ObservationFactXmlDbLoader.process(ObservationFactXmlDbLoader.java:84)
at edu.harvard.i2b2.crc.loader.xml.TypePullParser.doParsing(TypePullParser.java:73)...
```

Here is the part of ObservationFactDAO.java causing the problem (as referenced by the error):

```
    protected void insert(ObservationType observationType) {

        Object[] objs = new Object[] {
                observationType.getEventId().getValue(),
                observationType.getEventId().getSource(),
                observationType.getConceptCd().getValue(),
                (observationType.getPatientId() != null) ? observationType
                        .getPatientId().getValue() : null,
                (observationType.getPatientId() != null) ? observationType
                        .getPatientId().getSource() : null,
                (observationType.getObserverCd() != null) ? observationType
                        .getObserverCd().getValue() : null,
                (observationType.getStartDate() != null) ? observationType
                        .getStartDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
                        : null,
                (observationType.getModifierCd() != null) ? observationType
                        .getModifierCd().getValue() : null,
                (observationType.getInstanceNum() != null) ? observationType
                        .getInstanceNum().getValue()
                        : null,
                observationType.getValuetypeCd(),
                observationType.getTvalChar(),
                (observationType.getNvalNum() != null) ? observationType
                        .getNvalNum().getValue() : null,
                (observationType.getValueflagCd() != null) ? observationType
                        .getValueflagCd().getValue()
                        : null,
                (observationType.getQuantityNum() != null) ? observationType
                        .getQuantityNum()
                        : null,

                null,
                (observationType.getObservationBlob() != null) ? observationType
                        .getObservationBlob().getContent().get(0)
                        .toString()
                        : null,
                observationType.getUnitsCd(),
                (observationType.getEndDate() != null) ? observationType
                        .getEndDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
                        : null,
                (observationType.getLocationCd() != null) ? observationType
                        .getLocationCd().getValue() : null,
                (observationType.getUpdateDate() != null) ? observationType
                        .getUpdateDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
                        : null,
                (observationType.getDownloadDate() != null) ? observationType
                        .getDownloadDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
                        : null,
                (observationType.getImportDate() != null) ? observationType
                        .getImportDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime()
                        : null,
                observationType.getSourcesystemCd(),
                observationType.getUploadId() };
        update(objs);
    }
```

More specifically, the first line `Object[] objs = new Object[]` is referenced.

As you can see, the list is being defined here so I don't understand why the exception is sent here.

The methods called in the Object declaration are valid and simple 'return' statements. Furthermore, I've tried replacing them with actual values with the same results.

I'm still researching on my end but most of the existing posts about this exception concern adding values to an existing empty list and not its initialization.

Comment: I'd start by rewriting that awful looking array initializer so that at least it's readable

Comment: An array list is throwing the error. It doesn't have anything to do with the Object[].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with the array declaration, that simply cannot throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but with the `ArrayList` you're accessing in order to get one of the elements to put in the array you're creating. Specifically:

```
(observationType.getObservationBlob() != null) ? observationType
    .getObservationBlob().getContent().get(0)
    .toString()
    : null
```

If `getObservationBlob().getContent()` is empty, `get(0)` will throw this exception, so you should explicitly check against it:

```
(observationType.getObservationBlob() != null && 
 observationType.getObservationBlob().getContent() != null &&
 !observationType.getObservationBlob().getContent().isEmpty()) ? 
    observationType.getObservationBlob().getContent().get(0).toString()
    : null
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get why the exception now. Your solution seems appropriate but is there a particular import for the 'isEmpty()' function? i get an error in compilation

Comment: specifically 'symbol not found'

Comment: @RomainB. My mistake - you're supposed to apply `isEmpty()` on the ArrayList returned by `getContent()` - see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , saved me on this one ! good day to you fine sir ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Exception trace is clearly indicating that line 359 of ObservationFactDAO.java is calling get(0) on arraylist and there is no element at index 0 , which means arraylist is empty at this point.

It can be because it is expected that there would be some data in array at this point of code which is not there due to some data issue or its a problem in logic.

Comment: It is not an array that is empty but an `ArrayList` (as is clearly stated in the stack trace).

Comment: Thanks for clarification.